# MySQL not using index for two column date range

Tags: mysql

I have a table with millions of rows that has 2 `DATE` columns that are used to specify a start and end date range. I have a single index for the two columns but it doesn't get used and the query takes 10 seconds to run which is completely unacceptable. My query is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `valid_from` <= "2013-05-05" AND `valid_to` >= "2013-05-05"
```

Why is this not using the index and taking so long to run?

**Edit**

An `EXPLAIN` for the query above:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type   | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE        | events | ALL  | valid_from_to | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  2166894 | Using where|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: use the EXPLAIN and post the result here please.

Comment: @medina I posted the `EXPLAIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check fields order in index and in your query. 
Also, show

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `valid_from` <= "2013-05-05" AND `valid_to` >= "2013-05-05"
```

Try to use index hints

```
SELECT * FROM `events` USE INDEX (`valid_from_to`)
WHERE `valid_from` <= "2013-05-05" AND `valid_to` >= "2013-05-05"
```

Or make two indexes for each field instead of one.

Comment: That's rather a good comment, but not an answer to OP's question

Comment: Index hinting does nothing and index forcing causes the `EXPLAIN` to claim that it uses the index yet it still scans all 2 million rows and still takes 10 seconds to run

Comment: @zoonman Adding separate indexes for each of the columns fixed the problem but I can't imagine that is very efficient. Is there no better way?

Comment: I suppose, there is a problem with Query Optimizer. You can read this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/22/multiple-column-index-vs-multiple-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, nathanjosiah:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `events` FORCE INDEX (valid_from_to)
WHERE `valid_from` <= "2013-05-05" AND `valid_to` >= "2013-05-05"
```

The FORCE INDEX should solve your problem. ;-)

Comment: Doing this causes the `EXPLAIN` to claim that it uses the index yet it still scans all 2 million rows and still takes 10 seconds to run